# how to map table template to ng-grid using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

i am trying to use ng-grid saw documentation as well but not able to implement my previous simple table tamplete to ng-grid.if any one can update and show my example to plunker must be appreciated. Thanx.

Sending image before how it was looking and now i want to convert on ng-grid .
here is a image link previous table look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oHqu.png

**jsonFormat:-**

```
[Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
0: Resource
address1: "street 2"
address2: "street 1"
latitude: "121"
longitude: "121"
name: "Candy"
__proto__: Resource
1: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**previous Tamplate:-**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered ordersTable TableStyle" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >Name</th>
                <th >Location</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <tr data-ng-hide="stores.length > 0 " class="error">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="text-center"><strong>No Stores found</strong></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">


                <td>
                    {{ store.name }}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <span>{{ store.address1 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ store.address2 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ store.latitude }}</span>
                    <span>{{ store.longitude }}</span>
                </td>

                <td class="icons-width">
                    <a ng-click='openStoreModal(store._id)' id="edit"  data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw colorInfo" ></i>

                    </a>

                    <a ng-click="deleteStore(store._id)"  id="delete"  data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                    </a>

                </td>

            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**javascript Part**

```
 Store.getAllStores.TypeGetStores({}, $cookies.token, function(response){

                  //  $rootScope.stores = response; that line for previous template for new one tring this but showing nggrim undefined like.

$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: response,
            columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Address 1'}, {field:'address1', displayName:'Address 1'}, {field:'address2', displayName:'Address 2'}, {field:'latitude', displayName:'Latitude'}, {field:'longitude', displayName:'Longitude'}]
        };


                    console.log(response);

            },function(errorResponse){
                    delete $cookies['token'];
                    $location.url('/Login');
              }
            );
```

**New HtmlFor Grid**

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: what part of the mapping don't you understand? Examples are fairly easy to follow. What have you tried?

Comment: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined showing this error after update things you can see in my question

Comment: create a demo in plunker that replicates problem. Can create a `data.json` file ( or any name you want) to store some data for the $http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the way you retrieve data, you may need to use `Store.getAllStores.query(...)`, see the associate documentation.

On the HTML part you just need this :

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Then on your controller, pass your data by using the `$scope` (and not the `$rootScope` or `response` variable) to the `$scope.gridOptions` variable :

```
$scope.stores = response;

$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'stores',
            columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Address 1'}, {field:'address1', displayName:'Address 1'}, {field:'address2', displayName:'Address 2'}, {field:'latitude', displayName:'Latitude'}, {field:'longitude', displayName:'Longitude'}]
};
```

You will need to use cellTemplate property to custom some columns.

Finally a bit of CSS to adapt the template to your needs and it's done.

Comment: i have been updated my question can u look now what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I think it will not work with the $rootScope and it's not where your data are supposed to be. You need to set your data on $scope.stores, passing it with the variable response will not work too.

Comment: can you just verify this line how your wiiling to modify just modify that particular line.

Comment: i updated code as u mentioned in your answer but now facing this error
TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined
    <div class="gridStyle ng-scope" ng-grid="gridOptions">

Comment: Are you sure $scope.stores is not undefined ? What does it contains ? It needs a well formated list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41999/discussion-between-tomahim-and-wajihurrehman)

Comment: and it's getting objects u can see this result i am showing after response cam back from server.